# Back button to move nth page of datatable

Tags: jquery, grails, datatables

Let Suppose We have n page in data table and one column of this data-table have link to open new page(dashboard) by sending a new request.

we have to add back button over this new page(dashboard),such that this should move us to last opened page of data-table.

we applied back button like this-

```
<button style="postion:fixed;" class="pull-right" onclick="window.history.go(-1); ">Back</button>
```

but this button send us to first page of data table rather than nth page where we open the link.
            [image]

Answer (score 1):

First save the position of the current page in localstorage and then redirect to the new page
When you go back to the table  if localstorage has that variable and open the datatable a that page using `fnPageChange()`:

```
var table = $('#data_table').dataTable();
table.fnPageChange(localStorage.getItem('page'),true);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can save the page number in the hash of the first URL like this:

```
<a href="secondPage.html" onClick="window.location.hash = encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify({page: table.current_page_in_table}));">link</a>
```

Then upon loading of your page check if you have a hash and if so read the page number and update the table to go to that page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function goToRightPage() {
        if (window.location.hash) {
            // Read the hash string omitting the # prefix
            var hashJson = window.location.hash.substring(1);
            // Restore the deserialized data to memory
            myData = JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent(hashJson));
            datatable.goToPage(myData.page);
         }
    }
    window.onload = goToRightPage;
</script>
```